# Why is the return value of the first sbrk different than subsequent calls?

Tags: c, memory, sbrk, brk

I am trying to understand how memory works in C, so am experimenting with the `sbrk` function now. I know that `sbrk(0)` should return the current program break, that is the end of the data segment.

So I tried to call `sbrk(0)` multiple times and for some reason I get the first value different than the other values. For example, this program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
        void * currpb = sbrk(0);
        printf("The current program break is: %p.\n", currpb);

        void * newpb = sbrk(0);
        printf("The current program break is: %p.\n", newpb);

        void *new2pb = sbrk(0);
        printf("The current program break is: %p.\n", new2pb);

        void *new3pb = sbrk(0);
        printf("The current program break is: %p.\n", new3pb);
}
```

Give me the following output:

```
The current program break is: 0x18b0000.
The current program break is: 0x18d1000.
The current program break is: 0x18d1000.
The current program break is: 0x18d1000.
```

Am not sure why the 1st value is different than the other three values, any ideas?

Comment: (Your printfs are wrong; `new2pb` isn't an `int`.) [Fixed demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/cstMFRl8F2e29VT3)

Comment: hmmm, then what is it ?

Comment: Errr... a `void *`? It's your variable, you should know, you made it! :-) You need the `%p` format specifier, or otherwise cast the pointer to an appropriate integral type (e.g. `uintptr_t`) and use an appropriate specifier. But `%p` should be just fine to demonstrate the situation nicely. (Nice question, by the way.)

Comment: Yeppers, that makes sense, ok I used %p and it returned the address, i will edit my question

Comment: Never a dupe for such a specific question has been so exact. Indeed, when I saw this question I thought that it was that old one that got bumped up for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `printf`, it is calling/using `malloc`, which will do its own calls to `sbrk/brk` to allocate some space and add it to the memory heap/pool.

The *first* one has to allocate some space, so the `sbrk` value goes up. The subsequent ones can reuse that space, so they don't do their own `sbrk` again. But, they now have the `sbrk` value that has been perturbed by the first `printf` call.

If you use `write` and save the output to a file and examine it with a hex editor, you don't have the same problem. All values are the same:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main()
{
    void *pb;

    pb = sbrk(0);
    write(1,&pb,sizeof(pb));

    pb = sbrk(0);
    write(1,&pb,sizeof(pb));

    pb = sbrk(0);
    write(1,&pb,sizeof(pb));

    pb = sbrk(0);
    write(1,&pb,sizeof(pb));

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is the hex output:

```
00000000: 00908401 00000000 00908401 00000000  ................
00000010: 00908401 00000000 00908401 00000000  ................
```

---

Another [simpler] way to see this is to do all `sbrk` calls without the intervening `printf`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main()
{
    void *pb[4];

    for (int idx = 0;  idx < 4;  ++idx)
        pb[idx] = sbrk(0);

    for (int idx = 0;  idx < 4;  ++idx)
        printf("pb=%p sbrk=%p\n",pb[idx],sbrk(0));

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this is:

```
pb=0xc42000 sbrk=0xc42000
pb=0xc42000 sbrk=0xc63000
pb=0xc42000 sbrk=0xc63000
pb=0xc42000 sbrk=0xc63000
```